# CSS: button inside flexbox has smaller width than the content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here's my code, I've simplified the structure.
So we can focus on the difference between `button` and `div`
I have no idea why the text inside `button` will overflow and be cropped.
The `button` doesn't grow up to fit the content but the `div` does.
(I find this problem on Windows Chrome, while Firefox seems to be okay)

My workaround solution is to replace `button` with `div`.
I wonder if someone can explain the difference between `button` and `div`
Why `div` is okay with the same style?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .flexbox {
            display: flex;
        }
        .btn {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #dc447d;
            border: 0 solid #dc447d;
            padding: 0 3%;
            line-height: 1.63em;
            font-size: 17.2px;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 5px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flexbox">
        <button class="btn">
            <span>Start Free Trial</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="btn">
            <span>Start Free Trial</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems your code works fine on the jsfiddle...

Comment: @huanfeng I pasted to jsfiddle, it seemed to have the same result as I mentioned at the first time. If I re-run the code, it will render correctly. I don't know why.

Comment: It seems the strange issue is caused by you setting padding to a percentage value.

Comment: it's a chrome bug ... works fine in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Change padding to a number value should fix the issue.

Padding percentage is based on the parent element’s width

`padding: 0 10px`

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #dc447d;
  border: 0 solid #dc447d;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 1.63em;
  font-size: 17.2px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <button class="btn">
      <span>Start Free Trial</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="btn">
    <span>Start Free Trial</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's the closest answer which changes the layout as little as possible. 
But I still wonder someone can explain why div is okay in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated solution [here](https://codepen.io/Riddhi/pen/PoNKdMK), I've make my codepen link please refer it.

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #dc447d;
  border: 0 solid #dc447d;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 1.63em;
  font-size: 17.2px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this and got it to work? It doesn't make any difference when it is added to the code in the question, so please update your answer to explain how to get it to work.

Comment: @FluffyKitten, yes I already tried this solution in codepen, it worked for me.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't work when added to the Stack Snippet in the question, so please explain how the OP can get it to work in their code here.

Comment: @Riddhi, I also tried your suggestion in codepen, it didn't work

Comment: @Riddhi looks like the key is changing the padding from percentage to pixel

Comment: yes @Yung-DaLinLynda, you are correct, I tried my last solution as you said earlier, it wasn't work, yes it works sometime, it doesn't, so I implement another one which is this... and if you remove padding totally it will also work...

Answer (score 0):

Check out this snippet:

```css
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.btn {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #dc447d;
    border: 0 solid #dc447d;
    padding: 0 3%;
    line-height: 1.63em;
    font-size: 17.2px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flexbox">
        <button class="btn">
            <span>Start Free Trial</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="btn">
            <span>Start Free Trial</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

First thing first, I have added extra `<br/>` just to display things properly with clear borders.

Now inside `.flexbox` css, `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;` are used to align contents perfectly at the center of flex-box.

Furthermore, inside `.btn` `width: 100%;` is used to  make the content width up to the 100% of flex-box. You can alter this and can also play with `height: 100%` property if you want, for which you need to increase the height of flex-box.

Finally `text-align: center;` is used for `<div class="btn">` only, to center its content's horizontally.

Comment: The reason I didn't expand the button to full width is that I actually have another button aside (which I removed for simplicity). In my case, I use `justify-content: space-between` & `align-items: baseline` to arrange two elements. I knew expanding to full or adding `flex-grow` solves but it is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flexbox {
  display: inline flex;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #dc447d;
  border: 0 solid #dc447d;
  padding: 0 3%;  
  line-height: 1.63em;
  font-size: 17.2px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.
```

Using inline flex instead of flex fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work, while the layout changes
Can anyone explain the miracle? 

btw, it should be `inline-flex`